# Jquery div not selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select a div

```
<section class="grid">
 <div class="results clearfix">
 ....
 </div>
</section>
```

when i try the following code

```
 var sortGridList = $(".grid > .results");
```

It works fine

similarly i have another section

```js
var sortMapList = $(".map > .results");

console.log(sortMapList.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="map">
   <div class="col-sm-4 results">
   Sample Text
   </div>
</section>
```

It does not work

Is there anything wrong in the above code?

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is working as expected

Comment: I see, It is working fine!

Comment: Please take a look at your question again. The example you provides outputs the text to the console. Maybe you made a mistake when posting?

Comment: yes sorry i made a mistake. Apologies everyopne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything as such which caused its for not working . Have a look at 
`console` for errors if there is any for more clarification .

```js
var sortGridList = $(".grid > .results");
sortGridList.css("background-color", "yellow");

var sortMapList = $(".map > .results") ;
sortMapList.css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="grid">
 <div class="results clearfix">
 ....
 </div>
</section>

<hr>

   <section class="map">
     <div class="col-sm-4 results">
     ....
     </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Don't post answers saying it works. They doesn't help anyone and are pretty useless for future users. An answer should solve an issue, not state it already works.